# jQuery slideshow with different animations on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, slideshow

I want to build a jQuery slideshow in which HTML elements within each "slide" animate differently.

This would mean 3 divs that slide out to the left staggered, so 2 would have delays, to be replace by equivalent divs from the next "slide" coming in in the same way, but from the right.

There would also be 2 divs that would need to fade out to be replace by content from the next "slide" that would fade in.

Is this something i would have to write from scratch? Or is there some plugin that could be tailored to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If I were You, I will choose a plugin instead of writing from scratch because zillions of available plugin about slideshow out there

Comment: @user1479606: I agree, why write something that has already been done. You are just wasting development time. Unless you want to learn more JavaScript and or jQuery, in that case, I would recommend you write the script yourself.

Comment: None of these comments/answers give this user an answer. All just suggest going out and find a plugin, but without helping them find the plugin that fits their needs. I feel bad for you Emile =[ I'm looking for the same thing. I'll post a plugin if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Before you get too specific with your requirements, see what transitions and effects are available with an easy-to-use plugin. Then set your requirements based on what can be achieved with the library you choose.

I highly recommend Nivo Slider http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ See if you can achieve a satisfactory result with what they offer.

I've also had good experience with http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Both are easy to implement and offer a variety of transitions and effects.

Answer (score 0):

'80 Awesome jQuery Slider Plugins'
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/10/jquery-slider.html